# I don't know how to introduce myAge as not an integer without it showing up in the output

Tags: java

I have the error of bad operand types for binary operator '<' I'm not sure how to fix it. I'm very new to coding so I only really know the basics.

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class HowOldAreYou
{
public static void main(String args[])
   {
    
    int myAge = 16;
    
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    String userName;
    System.out.print("What is your name? ");
    userName = user_input.next();
    String userAge;
    System.out.print("How old are you? ");
    userAge = user_input.next();
    System.out.println("-----------------------");
    
    System.out.print("Your name is: " + userName);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("You are " + userAge + " years old.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("You are older than me: " + (myAge < userAge));
    
    
  }  
}
```

Comment: myAge is an int; userAge is a String. How can you compare them?

Comment: Why don't you want to use nextInt() though, because cursor stays there? Just use nextLine() again if that's why you're avoiding nextInt().

Answer (score 1):

You cant compare `String` to `int` , you need to get a int from the user and not a string , int is used for numbers that do not start with 0, for example age / price / year:

```
 int myAge = 16;
        
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String userName;
        System.out.print("What is your name? ");
        userName = user_input.next();
        int userAge;
        System.out.print("How old are you? ");
        userAge = user_input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        
        System.out.print("Your name is: " + userName);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("You are " + userAge + " years old.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You are older than me: " + (myAge < userAge));
```

**Output :**

```
What is your name? Pluto
How old are you? 20
-----------------------
Your name is: Pluto
You are 20 years old.
You are older than me: true
```

Answer (score 0):

So your issue if you are comparing an integer with a string, which cannot compare directly. The change I made should resolve this

```
public class HowOldAreYou
{
public static void main(String args[])
   {
    
    int myAge = 16;
    
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    String userName;
    System.out.print("What is your name? ");
    userName = user_input.next();
    **int userAge;**
    System.out.print("How old are you? ");
    **userAge = Integer.parseInt(user_input.next());**
    System.out.println("-----------------------");
    
    System.out.print("Your name is: " + userName);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("You are " + userAge + " years old.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("You are older than me: " + (myAge < userAge));
    
    
  }  
}
```

Comment: This was so helpful. I've been trying to fix it for so long. Thank you!!!

Comment: In the answer above mine, their way of getting the int is actually the acceptable way, mine still gets the job done though